# Maximize probability of blue ball

Tags: probability

You have 3 containers each of capacity of 300 balls. container A has 100 green balls, container B has 100 blue balls, container C has 100 yellow balls. shift the balls between containers so as to maximize the probability of finding a blue ball .

Comment: You need to phrase it better. What do you mean with "finding a blue ball"? Find it where? How many balls are you going to pick? From where?

Comment: Also provide your thoughts and attempts.

Comment: Sorry, it is my first question here. I will take care of this from the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you randomly choose a ball out of a random container...

Put one blue ball in the first container, one blue ball in the second container, and the remaining 98 blue balls plus the 100 green and 100 yellow balls in the third container.  The probably of picking a blue ball is $P(blue)=1*(\frac{1}{3})+1*(\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{98}{298})*(\frac{1}{3})$.